# Avoid Areas not working in Routing V8 REST API

Tags: here-api

Couldn't find a solution so here it goes. I'm trying to avoid a specific area when asking for routing directions. I've made test with both v7 and v8. The v7 works perfectly and avoids the zone but the v8 doesn't. I entered the same parameters (lat and lon) and is not working, does anyone has this error?

I know is managed differently in the docs but it stills doesn't work for v8 :/

```
V7 --> avoidareas=19.352167,-99.196818;19.351126,-99.194004

V8 --> avoid[areas]=bbox:19.352167,-99.196818,19.351126,-99.194004
```

[What I'm using in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBboI.png)

I'm looking for coordinates in Latin America, I don't know if the are some location limits in V8 :/ It works in v7 though

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To anyone that might be lost, the solution is that throughout the API the coordinates are handled latitude first and then longitude (this applies to both origin and destination)

origin = (latitude) , (longitude)
destination = (latitude), (longitude)

However for avoiding areas is the other way around.

If you were to map the box like the south west corner and the north east corner it would be something like this:

avoid[areas] = (longitude sw),(latitude sw),(longitude ne),(latitude ne)

My error was that I didn't look at the API reference with detail and assumed that there was a standard on handling coordinates. My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Below V8 routing request is working which contains all parameters(including avoid[areas]) and values provided in screen print:

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?destination=19.350952,-99.193858&origin=19.352458,-99.197319&transportMode=pedestrian&avoid[areas]=bbox:13.082,52.416,13.628,52.626&apikey=API_KEY&return=polyline,actions,instructions

Could you please check and revert.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry figured what is wrong, I thought there was a standard like the latitude was first and later the longitude. My bad! So its bbox: longitude,latitude, longitude,latitude. I got confused because both origin and destination goes lat first and then lon... I just assumed it was handled like that throughout all the routing API My bad!!

Comment: BTW :) I can finally teach my class how to use your API hehe I'm mentoring a 4 girls thank you for pointing it out.