# Avoid Areas not working with MULTIPLE bbox - Routing V8 REST API

Tags: routes, here-api

I have been trying to use the V8 REST API to create multiple bboxes that routing will avoid. Unlike this question asked previously: [Avoid Areas not working in Routing V8 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445372/avoid-areas-not-working-in-routing-v8-rest-api)

I am trying to avoid multiple bboxes rather than just one. With avoiding one bbox the routing algorithm works fine, but the syntax is not correct for two or more and there is lacking documentation regarding this. In previous versions and other APIs like java script, the common syntax is something like:

avoidareas = (long sw)(lat sw);(long ne)(lat se)!(long sw)(lat sw);(long ne)(lat se)

Where ; separates different points in the same bbox and ! separates the different bboxes.

Here with V8 REST API, this syntax does not work and there is no documentation guiding how to use multiple bboxes in this format. I have tried the following formats for example:

```
&avoid[areas]=bbox:16.177665,58.589032;16.178290,58.589303!16.177184,58.592806;16.177381,58.593079
&avoid[areas]=bbox:16.177665,58.589032,16.178290,58.589303,bbox:16.177184,58.592806,16.177381,58.593079
&avoid[areas]=bbox:16.177665,58.589032,16.178290,58.589303;16.177184,58.592806,16.177381,58.593079
```

When trying to simply add &avoid[areas] twice to make two bbox like the following:

```
&avoid[areas]=bbox:16.177665,58.589032,16.178290,58.589303
&avoid[areas]=bbox:16.177184,58.592806,16.177381,58.593079
```

I get the following error:Error while parsing request: Parameter 'avoid[areas]' specified more than once

I am not sure what syntax to use in order to create multiple but with one I am able to do route avoidance.The documentation provided by HERE developers that I am following is this:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.20.1/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/avoid.html

Any clarification regarding this is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Will not help with the documentation but correct way to define multiple avoided areas-bboxes is like this| pipe separated

```
&avoid[areas]=bbox:13.38549,52.52836,13.375606,52.523514|bbox:13.407838,52.528001,13.398397,52.524411|bbox:13.39943,52.522661,13.389989,52.519565
```

Working query example:

[https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=enXkNMMcTAmdM_W5p09e9pg25yyIpAK3WUPnSazveiA&origin=52.514717,13.381876&destination=52.536571,13.406953&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions&transportMode=car&avoid[areas]=bbox:13.38549,52.52836,13.375606,52.523514|bbox:13.407838,52.528001,13.398397,52.524411|bbox:13.39943,52.522661,13.389989,52.519565](https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=enXkNMMcTAmdM_W5p09e9pg25yyIpAK3WUPnSazveiA&origin=52.514717,13.381876&destination=52.536571,13.406953&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions&transportMode=car&avoid%5Bareas%5D=bbox:13.38549,52.52836,13.375606,52.523514%7Cbbox:13.407838,52.528001,13.398397,52.524411%7Cbbox:13.39943,52.522661,13.389989,52.519565)